# Dynamically get value from column1 and assign it to NaN values in same column, if they all have the same column2 value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
      ID  DESCRIPTION TYPE1 TYPE2
12345678 EXAMPLENAME1 874.4   NaN
12345678 EXAMPLENAME2 854.4   NaN
12345678 EXAMPLENAME3 874.4   B-5
78978999 EXAMPLENAME2 788.8   B-9
78978999 EXAMPLENAME4 978.2   NaN
78978999 EXAMPLENAME1 288.3   NaN
92124566 EXAMPLENAME3 369.1   NaN
92124566 EXAMPLENAME3 289.1   B-3
92124566 EXAMPLENAME3 959.1   NaN
```

I want to get all the `TYPE2` column that have the same ID with the value that is not `NaN`. We can assume that:

1. Only one `TYPE2` row per ID will have a nonnull value.
2. `TYPE2` is unique per each ID.

Final product should look like this:

```
      ID  DESCRIPTION TYPE1 TYPE2
12345678 EXAMPLENAME1 874.4   B-5
12345678 EXAMPLENAME2 854.4   B-5
12345678 EXAMPLENAME3 874.4   B-5
78978999 EXAMPLENAME2 788.8   B-9
78978999 EXAMPLENAME4 978.2   B-9
78978999 EXAMPLENAME1 288.3   B-9
92124566 EXAMPLENAME3 369.1   B-3
92124566 EXAMPLENAME3 289.1   B-3
92124566 EXAMPLENAME3 959.1   B-3
```

I've tried with `ffill`, but can't establish the condition to fill only when ID is the same. There are about 1,500,000 different `TYPE2` and `ID` values, so manually establish them like `df.loc[df["ID"]="12345678", "TYPE2"] = "B-5"` wouldn't work.

How can I have `df.loc` check if the `ID` is the same, then grabbing the nonnull value from `TYPE2` and assing it to the rest of the `ID` rows? Are there any other methods to get the same outcome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To fill null values ​​within each ID we must first use `.groupby` and then combine `.bfill()` and `.ffill()`

```
df['TYPE2'] = df.groupby('ID')['TYPE2'].bfill().ffill()
#result
    ID          DESCRIPTION     TYPE1   TYPE2
0   12345678    EXAMPLENAME1    874.4   B-5
1   12345678    EXAMPLENAME2    854.4   B-5
2   12345678    EXAMPLENAME3    874.4   B-5
3   78978999    EXAMPLENAME2    788.8   B-9
4   78978999    EXAMPLENAME4    978.2   B-9
5   78978999    EXAMPLENAME1    288.3   B-9
6   92124566    EXAMPLENAME3    369.1   B-3
7   92124566    EXAMPLENAME3    289.1   B-3
8   92124566    EXAMPLENAME3    959.1   B-3
```

Comment: Thanks @Terry, just what I needed. Quick note: Had to use `.ffill().bfill()`; using `.bfill()` first let to some values not properly established and mixed.